# Substitute of Minus in MySQl

Tags: mysql

I Have two queries

```
  1) select count(*) from first where active='1'

  2) select count(*) 
     from first a left outer join second b 
         on a.pid=b.project_id and a.project_name=b.project_name 
     where a.entry_date='2014-01-01'
```

For first I am getting 106 and second i am getting 86.
I want to display the 106-83=26, 26 rows. The rows should contain details not only count.
I already tried Not Exists and Not In.
here in both table composite keys have been used project_id and project_name

i tried this, but returning 0 rows found

```
 select a.project_id, a.project_name 
 from first a 
 where a.active='1' and 
 NOT Exists(
     select  b.project_id, b.project_name 
     from first a 
     left outer join second b on a.pid=b.project_id 
     and a.project_name=b.project_name 
     where a.entry_date='2014-01-16');
```

please help if any one have any idea, how to do it.

Comment: `select count(*) from first a inner join second b on a.pid=b.project_id and   a.project_name=b.project_name where a.entry_date='2014-01-01'`

Comment: It is returning 83 rows as count, how to achieve the other 23 rows difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from first 
where active='1'
and (pid, project_name) NOT IN (
  select project_id, project_name 
  from second
  where entry_date='2014-01-01'
)
```

Comment: select * from first where active='1' returns 106 rows and select * from second where entry_date='2014-01-17' returning 78 rows, so the difference is 28, why the above query is returning 31 rows..it should return 28?

Comment: @ajitksharma maybe caused by duplicates or null data. please check your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from first a inner join second b
on a.pid=b.project_id and a.project_name=b.project_name 
where a.active='1' and a.entry_date<>'2014-01-01'
```